# Google map is not displaying in android appication

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin

I am developing an android map application in xamarin. I had done all the things

Created API key
Generated SH1 KEY
give all the required permission. but still I am getting grey area in the map. I am facing this issue from 2 days. None of article helped me.

Here is my Manifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="Param.Param">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<application android:label="Param" android:icon="@drawable/icon">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"    android:value="AIzaSyCy_xogJYFs3nita-S8DHXnLE83z-B_FUw" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<!-- Google Maps for Android v2 requires OpenGL ES v2 -->
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
<!-- We need to be able to download map tiles and access Google Play Services-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- Allow the application to access Google web-based services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!-- Google Maps for Android v2 will cache map tiles on external storage -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- Google Maps for Android v2 needs this permission so that it may check the connection state as it must download data -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- Permission to receive remote notifications from Google Play Services -->
<!-- Notice here that we have the package name of our application as a prefix on the permissions. -->
<uses-permission android:name="param.param.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="param.param.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<!-- These are optional, but recommended. They will allow Maps to use the My Location provider. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And here is my code

```
namespace P
{
[Activity (Label = "map")]          
public class map : Android.GoogleMaps.MapActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Map);
        // Create your application here

        Button takeMeThere = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.buttonTake);

        takeMeThere.Click += delegate {
            Toast.MakeText(this,"RR",ToastLength.Long).Show();
        };


        ////
        MapFragment mapFrag = (MapFragment) FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map);
        GoogleMap map = mapFrag.Map;
        if (map != null) {
            try{
            MarkerOptions markerOpt1 = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOpt1.SetPosition(new LatLng(50.379444, 2.773611));
            markerOpt1.SetTitle("Vimy Ridge");

            map.AddMarker(markerOpt1);
            map.MapType = GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal;
            markerOpt1.InvokeIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.pin_base));

            map.UiSettings.ZoomControlsEnabled = false;
            //map.UiSettings.CompassEnabled = true;
                //LatLng location = new LatLng(18.489057,73.924345);
                //CameraPosition.Builder builder =    CameraPosition.InvokeBuilder();
                //  builder.Target(location);
                //builder.Zoom(18);
//              builder.Bearing(155);
//              builder.Tilt(65);
//              CameraPosition cameraPosition = builder.Build();
//              CameraUpdate cameraUpdate =    CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
//              map.MoveCamera(cameraUpdate);
            }
            catch(Exception e){Toast.MakeText (this,e+"",ToastLength.Long).Show();}

        }
    }

    protected override bool IsRouteDisplayed {
    get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button
    android:layout_width="84.0dp"
    android:layout_height="40.0dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonback"
    android:textColor="#ffada8a8"
    android:text="Back"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/Back_icon"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:drawablePadding="-20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:text="Map"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="112.0dp"
    android:layout_height="40.0dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonback"
    android:id="@+id/textViewMap"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="295.7dp"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/map"
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
    android:background="#2F2E2C" />
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/Address_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/map"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />
<TextView
    android:text="Address"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/map"
    android:id="@+id/textViewaddress"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="85dp" />
<Button
    android:text="Take me there"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/map"
    android:id="@+id/buttonTake"
    style="@style/DefaultButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
```

Still I am getting grey area in map.
Can any one please tell me where I am doing mistake.

Comment: What is your layout? Have you tried debugging (is your map null?)

Comment: I added the layout and map in not null.

Comment: I would suggest starting with really basic layout (Linear Layout - vertical + map fragment) to see if that shows and then add layouts on top of it..

Comment: If you are getting a grey map it's a communication issue with the servers. Recheck your api key, did you activate google map in the google map console for ANDROID ? is your package name correct in the console ? Are you 100% sure ? If there is doubt ReCreate a debug apikey or release. Also if the map is grey there must be some log, check your logcat for warnings from the api =)

Comment: thanks for your reply I will recheck everything

Comment: Can you please tell me what is debug keystore and release keystore because I am using only one keystore which i use for sigining my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Add this permission into your manifest   
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

 And use support fragment
 GoogleMap  googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) (getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap();
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Use this in your xml <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.example.mapdemo.MainActivity"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

Comment: I solved the error I accept your ans for keyword `class`

Answer (score 0):

I think in Google API Console try to enable to Google map v2 in **services** tab

Comment: have you added the google play services as a reference project to your projects....

Comment: have you added <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />